# Textarea not focus after click on button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Textarea is disable on page load. Textarea will be enable after click on button. I want to add focus on textarea after textarea is enable on button click using javascript.

Here is my code:-

```
<div id="fav-focus"><textarea name="remark" id="remark'.$value['id'].'" rol="4" cols="20" class="fav-view" disabled="disabled">'.$value['remark'].'</textarea> </div>
<a id="favt_edit" class="editfavorite editfavorite'.$value['id'].' buttonNew greenB normal" title="'.$value['id'].'">Edit</a> 

<Script>document.getElementById('favt_edit').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('fav-focus').focus();
};
</script>
```

Kindly advice me any solution.

Comment: check the answer below for focusing the textarea

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('favt_edit').onclick = function() {
        document.getElementsByName('remark')[0].disabled = false;
        document.getElementsByName('remark')[0].focus();
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for enabling as well as focusing your textarea.

```
<script>document.getElementById('favt_edit').onclick = function() {

 $('#fav-focus').find('textarea').removeAttr('disabled').trigger('focus');
};
</script>
```

Replace your jquery function with this.It will definately work.

Comment: Just a single line code will perform both the operations (enabling and focusing).